# How can I delete one customer by ID using Session load() and then delete()?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, session, jboss

I'm trying to delete one customer on DB using the ID, so i first retrieve it ( and it works ) and then i use load() for get customer but doesn't work ...
It say "Error unknown 1146" ( table not exist ) .
The problem i think is that after the first query the session close so then i can't access to DB ...
I tryed to create another session after the first query with - 
Session session2 = (Session) this.entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);- and use that one but still having same error...
I hope you can help me beacuse i'm still learning all , sorry !!
Thank you.

public class DeleteCustomerProcessor 
implements Processor{

```
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RetrieveCustomerProcessor.class);

@PersistenceContext(unitName="customer-management-jpa") private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    Session session = (Session) this.entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

    UtenteRequest request = exchange.getIn().getBody(UtenteRequest.class);

    Integer id_customer = (Integer) session.createSQLQuery("SELECT id_customer FROM customers_management.customers " +
                                                 "WHERE name= :firstname AND surname= :surname")
                                                 .setParameter("firstname", request.getfirstName())
                                                 .setParameter("surname", request.getlastName())
                                                 .uniqueResult();

    log.info("############# ID " + id_customer);

    Customer customer= (Customer) session.load(Customer.class, id_customer);

    log.info("############# Customer " + customer.toString());

    session.delete(customer);


}   

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

}

```
Caused by:
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: could not extract ResultSet while invoking public abstract com.accenture.cpaas.vertical.longacretest.domain.CreateCustomerResponse com.accenture.cpaas.vertical.longacretest.rest.service.TestService.deleteCustomer(com.accenture.cpaas.vertical.longacretest.domain.UtenteRequest) with params [Utente [firstName=Ema, lastName=Gio]].
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.wrapExceptionAsFault(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:365)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:323)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.resume(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:277)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:78)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handleAsync(Server.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:984)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: could not extract ResultSet while invoking public abstract com.accenture.cpaas.vertical.longacretest.domain.CreateCustomerResponse com.accenture.cpaas.vertical.longacretest.rest.service.TestService.deleteCustomer(com.accenture.cpaas.vertical.longacretest.domain.UtenteRequest) with params [Utente [firstName=Ema, lastName=Gio]].
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:167)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:141)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:200)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2062)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:906)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2145)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3939)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1053)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.immediateLoad(SessionImpl.java:968)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at com.accenture.cpaas.vertical.longacretest.domain.Customer_$$_jvst7d3_7.toString(Customer_$$_jvst7d3_7.java)
    at com.accenture.cpaas.vertical.longacretest.endpoint.http.process.DeleteCustomerProcessor.process(DeleteCustomerProcessor.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler$1.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:119)
    at com.accenture.cpaas.vertical.longacretest.endpoint.http.process.$DeleteCustomerProcessor976648813.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RoutingSlip$2.doInAsyncProducer(RoutingSlip.java:311)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:304)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RoutingSlip.processExchange(RoutingSlip.java:304)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RoutingSlip.doRoutingSlip(RoutingSlip.java:225)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RoutingSlip.process(RoutingSlip.java:156)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsInvoker.asyncInvoke(CxfRsInvoker.java:93)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsInvoker.performInvocation(CxfRsInvoker.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:97)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:200)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown error 1146
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:941)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2470)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2550)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:701)
    at org.tranql.connector.jdbc.PreparedStatementHandle.executeQuery(PreparedStatementHandle.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
    ... 91 more
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the EntityManager `find`  method? Something like: `Employee employee = em.find(Employee.class, 1); //1 is the id`

Comment: Why on earth are you unwrapping the session? What possible reason is there to be messing around doing that here? Why get the Id and then load the Customer? Why not just load using the forename and surname???

Comment: @dcalap I must use Session methods not EntityManager sorry. Session.load() is the same as the one you say.

Comment: @AlanHay I must do like that ...orders ....with the unwrap and Session methods to get customers by id

Comment: Sorry but this code is complete rubbish and if someone is telling you to do it this way then you should tell them that.